# Controlling DC motors Using RaspberryPi and MDD10A motor driver

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am working on a robotic project and encountering difficulties in controlling two Dc motors. Anyway, I am using raspberry Pi 3 and Dual Channel 10A DC Motor Driver to drive two DC motors (Dual shaft self-locking DC worm gear motor). I am using the driver to drive bigger motor capacity and make them work as a servo motor. I managed to send signal and run the motors but I can't stop them running. Please any help, I would be thankful.

```
 Import  RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 import time 
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
 pwm=GPIO.PWM(12,100)
 pwm.start(20)
 time.sleep(1)
 pwm.stop()
```

In fact, I have little knowledge on controlling the motors.. if you can guide me or show me good reference I will also be grateful .

Comment: How are your motors wired up? I'm not sure how you'd control two motors from one GPIO pin. Do the motor(s) start under control of your software, and then just keep running after the program stops?

Comment: No sir. I am using two GPIO 10 and 12. Both of them are connecting to SmartDriveDuo-10 Motor Driver .. I think the wiring is correct as I can run the motors from python script as I mentioned. But I don't know how to stop them. And yes after complete execution the motors continue moving

Comment: I want to move them forward and backward in 180 degrees only.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what's wrong here. You need to be a bit careful about the GPIO pin numbering, because there are two different schemes in use. Also, my recollection is that only one pin has PWM control in hardware -- the others have to be simulated using software timing. I'm not sure how relevant that is. My approach would be to put a voltmeter on the appropriate pins, and check what the voltage is doing when you run your program -- ideally without the motor driver connected. continued...

Comment: It's possible that you need pull-up resistors on your GPIO outputs, else the voltage might "float" if the motor driver input resistance is high. Some PIs have built-in pull ups, but not all. A voltmeter might tell you if you have a problem like this. In any case, you'll find it very hard to make the motors turn _exactly_ 180 degrees -- "roughly" is probably the best you can hope for.

Comment: Thank for answering. Looking for more suggestions.